# Python index selection in a 3D list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, indices

I have the following 3D list:

```
test = [[[(x,y,z) for x in range(0,5)] for y in range(5,8)] for z in range(0,4)]
test[0].append([(0,5),(5,0)])
```

I want to select all the indices of the first dimension, the 0th index of the 2nd dimension and all the indices of the 3rd dimension.
If it was an array I would write `array[:,0,:]`.
However when I write `test[:][0][:]` it is the same as doing `test[0][:][:]` which is not what I want.

How could I do that ?

Comment: test[:][0][:] is essentially the same as test[0], because the [:] just selects the whole list. You can use that syntax to pinpoint specific elements, but selecting multiple is a whole different story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transpose and take the zeroeth item.

```
>>> list(zip(*test))[0]
([(0, 5, 0), (1, 5, 0), (2, 5, 0), (3, 5, 0), (4, 5, 0)],
 [(0, 5, 1), (1, 5, 1), (2, 5, 1), (3, 5, 1), (4, 5, 1)],
 [(0, 5, 2), (1, 5, 2), (2, 5, 2), (3, 5, 2), (4, 5, 2)],
 [(0, 5, 3), (1, 5, 3), (2, 5, 3), (3, 5, 3), (4, 5, 3)])
```

---

```
[thing[0] for thing in test]
```

---

Zeroeth item in the third dimension.

```
 [a[0] for b in test for a in b]
```